# Nokogiri: Removing all nodes that have a string NOT inside specific tag

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have a Nokogiri instance and I want to remove all nodes that have the text "TITLE OF ARTICLE" that are not inside a h1 tag?

```
htmlSource = "<HTML><H1>TITLE OF ARTICLE</H1><b>TITLE OF ARTICLE</b></HTML>"
nokogiri = Nokogiri::HTML(htmlSource)
headers = nokogiri.xpath('//h1')
#what to do next?
#I want the output to be <HTML><H1>TITLE OF ARTICLE</H1></HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

To exclude `h1` tag, you can use `*[name()!="h1"]`  xpath expression; then use [`NodeSet#remove`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#method-i-remove) to remove matched nodes.

```
matched = nokogiri.xpath('//*[name()!="h1"][text()="TITLE OF ARTICLE"]')
matched.remove()
```

Alternative using `css` method:

```
matched = nokogiri.css('*[name()!="h1"][text()="TITLE OF ARTICLE"]')
matched.remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do using [`Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet#remove`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#method-i-remove):

```
require 'nokogiri'

htmlSource = "<HTML><H1>TITLE OF ARTICLE</H1><b>TITLE OF ARTICLE</b></HTML>"
nokogiri = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(htmlSource)
node_to_remove = nokogiri.xpath('//*[not(self::h1) and .="TITLE OF ARTICLE"]')
node_to_remove.remove
puts nokogiri
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body><h1>TITLE OF ARTICLE</h1></body></html>
```

Comment: How do I make this generic? It might be other tags beside bold.